# Active tab (redirect to tab on sales order) in grid action Issue

Tags: adminhtml, grid

Active tab (redirect to the tab on sales order) in grid action, not open tab. ajax error "secret key incorrect" but secret key is correct not issue with a secret key.

Tab order_custom is highlighted but ajax return failed

Url which using for ajax request (failed) is using active tab:-

> magento_admin_url/sales/order/commentsHistory/order_id/202/active_tab/order_custom/key/7fc182a189d728b90ededb215fe1592b439d080a02ef7f3ae5c74724946f23fd/?isAjax=true&form_key=OkfJIr1IfRyVKMaA

Response :- You entered an invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page